# Rabbitmq - Need Fix for a error PLAIN login refused

Tags: python, json, rabbitmq

I need to listen for a particular message from a rabbit queue.

For eg: JSON response in queue notifications.info is as follows:

```
{"event_type": "compute.instance.create.end",
 "timestamp": "2012-03-12 17:00:24.156710",
 "message_id": "00004e00-8da5-4c39-8ffb-c94ed0b5278c",
 "priority": "INFO",
 "publisher_id": "compute.compute-1-5-6-7",
  .
  .
  .
```

So this is an JSON response or message which I am getting in a Queue notifications.info.

I need to listen synchronously for the particular message and also needs to perform certain operations after that.

Please anyone let me know the way for doing the same.

**EDIT**

Here I have elaborated in detail.This is what I have done so far.

Actually my aim is to get some notification on new instance creation.

So that I have set up the notifications.info to receive message during instance creation.

Now I have framed the basic script which is as follows(Using Rabbitmq site guide):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='nova',
                         type='direct')

result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue

severities = sys.argv[1:]
if not severities:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Usage: %s [info] [warning] [error]" % \
                         (sys.argv[0],)
    sys.exit(1)

for severity in severities:
    channel.queue_bind(exchange='nova',
                       queue=queue_name,
                       routing_key=severity)

print ' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C'

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print " [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body,)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue=queue_name,
                      no_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

There is more modifications were needs to be done in scipts.

But now issue is that while executing the script I am getting error which is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new1.py", line 6, in <module>
    host='localhost'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection                                                                                        .py", line 339, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection                                                                                        .py", line 374, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection                                                                                        .py", line 410, in _flush_output
    self._impl.ioloop.poll()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.p                                                                                        y", line 602, in poll
    self._process_fd_events(fd_event_map, write_only)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.p                                                                                        y", line 443, in _process_fd_events
    handler(fileno, events, write_only=write_only)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py"                                                                                        , line 364, in _handle_events
    self._handle_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py"                                                                                        , line 407, in _handle_read
    return self._handle_error(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py"                                                                                        , line 338, in _handle_error
    self._handle_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py"                                                                                        , line 288, in _handle_disconnect
    self._adapter_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.p                                                                                        y", line 95, in _adapter_disconnect
    super(SelectConnection, self)._adapter_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py"                                                                                        , line 154, in _adapter_disconnect
    self._check_state_on_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py"                                                                                        , line 173, in _check_state_on_disconnect
    raise exceptions.ProbableAuthenticationError
pika.exceptions.ProbableAuthenticationError
```

Log is showing the error is as follows:

```
{handshake_error,starting,0,
                 {amqp_error,access_refused,
                             "PLAIN login refused: user 'guest' - invalid credentials",
                             'connection.start_ok'}}
```

So some one let me know what is needs to be done here to fix this.

Note: I am able to access a rabbitmq front end with guest user.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? There are various Python libraries available for listening to a rabbitmq queue, what have you tried?

Answer (score -2):

I have found the issue.

Actually there was password conflict that is the reason why it results in such an error.

When I am configuring new password rather than default one for rabbitmq it results in an error,

So I tried using the default password 'guest' itself for 'guest' user.

Then the issue is fixed here.